# HTTP Status 500 - Mandatory TLD element jsp-version missing or empty in TLD WEB-INF/custom.tld

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

i am trying to run a simple custom jsp program but its not working , i am using tomcat 8.5  and ubuntu 14.04, i have also placed the custom.tld in WEB-INF older 
here is my code

```
enter code here

jsp code:
<%@taglib prefix="ab" uri="WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>

<ab:Hello />
java code :
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
public void doTag() throws IOException {
    JspWriter pw = getJspContext().getOut();
    pw.println("Welcome");
  }
} 

custom tld :
<taglib>
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<jsp-verion>2.0</jsp-verion>
<tag>
    <name>Hello</name>
    <tag-class>HelloTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `<jsp-verion>2.0</jsp-verion>`  with  `<jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>` and try again. Missing keyword `'s'`

Comment: i did the change , now i am getting a new error 

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /custom.jsp
unable to compile the class 

HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: 

1: <%@taglib uri="WEB-INF/custom.tld" prefix="ab" %>
2: 
3: <ab:Hello />

Comment: @NikhilGaikwad put HelloTag class in package. for example; com.model.HelloTag and access it <tag-class>com.model.HelloTag</tag-class>. Default package may occur problems.